# Android - Material Design - NavigationView ScrollBar and Thumb Color

Tags: android, material-design, android-navigationview

Is There any way to customize the NavigationView Scroll bar and thumb color.
Right now it is reported as  bug and can`t be customized.Link for bug is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179390)

Has anyone done customization in scroll view of navigationview do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of  RnD I found this solution that helps in changing thumb color dynamically not  in xml

```
 private void navigationViewScrollThumbColor(NavigationView navigationView) {

    if (navigationView != null) {
        NavigationMenuView navigationMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
        if (navigationMenuView != null) {
            try {
                Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
                mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
                Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(navigationMenuView);

                Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
                scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
                Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);

                Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(scrollBar, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.color_of_your_Choice));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```